# Turn Git CR-LF conversion off (not the warning message) in year 2022

Tags: git

There are plenty of resources that list several Git settings, like `core.autocrlf` or settings in `.gitattributes` file, to either turn CRLF auto conversion warning off or the conversion itself but none of them seems to work in year 2022 for git `2.27.0.windows.1`.

Actually I would like to have following:

- If LF - CRLF conversion will be performed - warn me.
- Turn CRLF conversion system wide off. Commit files always as they are.
- Interpret text files as text files. Do not try to outsmart Git by pretending that text files are binaries etc in order to turn CRLF conversion off.

Please suggest a working solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

To Git, the `text` attribute for a file means to perform line-ending conversion.  If you don't want to perform line-ending conversion, then you don't want to set the `text` attribute.

If you simply want to always commit files as they are, then you either need to do one of the following:

1. Set `* -text` in `.gitattributes`.  Diffs will still do autodetection for whether the file is text or binary.
2. Don't specify anything in `.gitattributes` and always set `core.autocrlf` to `input`.  This relies on every user of the repository having the same settings and therefore isn't recommended.

Those are the two options that are available: there are no other options to turn off line-ending conversion in Git.

Note that in both cases, Git will perform no input or output conversions at all, so no LF to CRLF conversion will be performed.  Similarly, Git will by default show carriage returns as trailing whitespace in new lines of diffs.